# Finding an IP address by MAC address

Tags: c#, network-programming, arp

I know this question has been asked before and that and my own findings rely on using the ARP functionality.

The problem is that ARP only contains entries of IP/MAC addresses that have been “initialized” by some application/code. It could even be as simple as just a ping.

I came across reverse ARP (NARP?) but could not find any sample code for it anywhere.

Is it possible to acquire an IP address by just knowing the MAC address?

I could ping the whole subnet, but that would be inefficient.

Comment: Is this for a private network?

Comment: HI, yes it is. On my own local network.

Comment: Pretty unclear what you are looking for.  How could you possible know the MAC numbers?  Pinging the sub-net is the obvious approach.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. I do know the mac address before hand.  And like I said pinging would be in-efficient I guess or..?

Comment: Sorry, missed that you said pinging the subnet?

Comment: the subnet mask I have is 255.255.255.0. Did you mean that? Thank you for your time BTW

Comment: How is your application acquiring the mac addresses? And what are you attempting to do that it wouldn't suffice to just query DNS using their hostname?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay.  I have an ip camera. Part of the registration process is logging in with the supplied macid.  This IP is set to DHCP.  So, I could ping each address and connect to the ip camera (using rtsp) and this works. But, i wanted to know if there was a quicker/efficent way to do things.  I cannot know for sure what the hostname will be unfortunately..

Comment: The quickest thing, IMHO, would be to see if you can assign the camera a static address.

Comment: Hi, that was my inital thinking but this ip camera model does not allow to set the ip via its sdk...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to integrate terminal command results on C# but I know you can get just the IP address scanning the Mac on your local network by implementing this command on a terminal.

```
sudo arp-scan --localnet | awk '/b8:27:/ { print $1 }'
```